# Mongo cannot find master during data lookups

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am running a large data update using pymongo. To run the updates, individual records are found using `collection.find_one(unique criteria)`, changes are made, the updates are batched, and finally sent in chunks using `db.collection.save([long list of records to save])`

On my local machine (running 1.6.3), the imports work fine.

On a remote server (running 1.6.0), which is much faster than my local machine, I can get through a portion of the inserts just fine, but then will suddenly get the following error when looking up original records:

```
connection = Connection(...)
...
raise AutoReconnect("could not find master/primary")
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not find master/primary
```

The number of records I can get through is varies somewhat, but is not random.

At first I thought I was running into the connection limit. I started closing connections manually after each record lookup:

```
collection.database.connection.disconnect()
```

Which didn't solve the problem. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Sounds like an unreliable network connection in between or someone closing the network channel in between. Firewall?

Comment: I will check on this. Both are running on the same local machine, and I'm connecting to mongo localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are a couple of potential issues here:

```
raise AutoReconnect("could not find master/primary") 
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not find master/primary
```

That error indicates that the existing connection has somehow been invalidated. There are a number of reasons this could happen.

The most common reason this happens is that that the Primary of a Replica Set has stepped down or has failed. In this case your code needs to:

1. Catch (or trap) the error.
2. Decide on a retry strategy. (fail? retry once?...)

Are you doing this?
Are you running Replica Sets or Master/Slave?
Do you have any tracking for the performance of these servers?
Are they having network issues?
Are they switching roles?

> collection.database.connection.disconnect()
>
> Which didn't solve the problem. Am I on the right track?

Where is the exception "happening"? Is it coming from the connection itself or the save command?

> On a remote server (running 1.6.0)

As of this writing, 1.6.0 is a very old version of MongoDB. There were multiple replication bugs fixed in the subsequent 1.6.x versions and 1.7.x versions. (we're already at 1.8.1rc-0)

I would start by looking at what's happening with your servers, but that may well lead you down the upgrade path.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem in interactive python usage with pymongo, where I leave the session idle and encounter AutoReconnect upon returning. I've handled it this way:

```
import functools
import pymongo
import time

MAX_AUTO_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS = 5

def graceful_auto_reconnect(mongo_op_func):
  """Gracefully handle a reconnection event."""
  @functools.wraps(mongo_op_func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    for attempt in xrange(MAX_AUTO_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS):
      try:
        return mongo_op_func(*args, **kwargs)
      except pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect as e:
        wait_t = 0.5 * pow(2, attempt) # exponential back off
        time.sleep(wait_t)

  return wrapper

@graceful_auto_reconnect
def some_func_that_does_mongodb_ops():
  ...
  ...
```

YMMV